Android10 Night Mode
I encountered an issue during development where, on Android 10 devices, after setting the daytime mode through AppLappatDetachate.setDefaultNightMode(AppLappatDetachate. MODE_NIGHT_YES), the system was still in nighttime mode, causing the app to obtain color resources using the - night resource, which resulted in me not achieving the desired effect. I'm not sure if anyone has relevant experience and can guide me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
